# Using Mac Automator to run Python Find & Replace. Multiline (\n\r) not working

Tags: python, macos, automator, find-replace

I'm using Mac Automator to run a 'Find & Replace' python script. (Below is a simplified version.) It's working really well, with the exception of line breaks...

I've tried multiple variants of \r \n \r\n but it's not removing the line breaks.

```
    replacements = {
    'class="spec-container"':'class="row"',
    '</span>\n\n':'</span>',
    '</div>\n\n\n':'</div>\n'
    }

    with open('/../TEMP/INPUT.txt') as infile, 
    open('/../TEMP/OUTPUT.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for find, replace in replacements.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(find, replace)
        outfile.write(line)
```

Really only just find my feet with Python, so apologies in advance. But any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `strip()` method for removing whitespace around a string in Python. `"hello\n".strip()` will return `"hello"`. You can also use `lstrip()` or `rstrip()` if you only want it to strip the string on one side.